# What techniques are there to extract a navigational menu from a web page?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, information-extraction, web-scraping

I'm looking for a method to extract a menu used for navigation from a web page heavy with links (and probably text). The pages I'm interested in are quite plain, valid XHTML, and it's a safe assumption that the menu is somewhere in the beginning or the end of the page. But a good, general, method to find where exactly it is has eluded me so far - and I hope you'll be able to help me with this.

A quick note: I'm not looking for something like Readability - to find the main article and strip everything else, but for something to specifically find the menu.
Also the naive method of "find an element that has a lot of links as successors" doesn't work very well - as the pages I tend to contain pretty long lists of links.

EDIT: I need the menu to get the content of the pages linked in it (I building a web scraper of sorts for an Information Extraction project).
Some example pages I works with:

- http://p2.cs.berkeley.edu/
- http://www.cs.cornell.edu/bigreddata/maybms/ (note: here I need the menu which points to publications/downloads not the sidebar navigation, but getting rid of the side bar navigation is easier using something like Readability).

Comment: Can you give a sample of the page?

Comment: **1**. What do you want to do with the menu? **2**. Can we see the page? Impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: Regarding sample pages - I've added some, but the main problem is that I'm looking for a solution as less page specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would compute the ratio of {sum of lengths of child element text *in* links} over {sum of lengths of child element text *out* of links}. If the ratio is above some threshold, and the absolute number of links is above some threshold, then you can assume that element contains a menu.

If that isn't enough you'd have to render the page (in a browser, or headless using a webkit library for example) to get the position on the page of the rendered elements.

Comment: Could you elaborate how rendering a page would help/can be used in an automatic setting?

Comment: Also there are standard names which should be used as features like "home", "about us" etc

Answer (score 0):

As Drag0nR3b0rn mentioned you should use link / non link text ratio + common menu words as features and manually/trained decision tree. For crawling I would reccommend HtmlUnit

Comment: Actually user481112 mentioned it